# Firebase scheduled functions - all fail to deploy but one

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have created 4 scheduled cloud functions:

```
export const a_scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun(a);
export const b_scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 22 * * *').onRun(b);
export const c_scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 21 * * *').onRun(c);
export const d_scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(d);
```

However, when I deploy them the first one (`a_scheduled`) deploys OK while the rest say the following error:

> !  functions: failed to create function b_scheduled HTTP Error: 400,
>   The request has errors !  functions: failed to create function
>   c_scheduled HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors !  functions:
>   failed to create function d_scheduled HTTP Error: 400, The request has
>   errors

It is unclear to me why such error happens. I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

Comment: Make sure your CLI is fully up to date, run the CLI deployment with the `--debug` flag, and if there is still an error, contact Firebase support with the output it generates.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Comment: New CLI sorted it! Thanks